# Access the force.com REST API with a pure Javascript page

Tags: javascript, rest, salesforce

I want to develop a front-end in Javascript (possibly with one of the fancy frameworks around such as AngularJS) that consumes the REST API of my Salesforce org.

I **don't want** to embed my project in Salesforce technologies, so basically

- no Visualforce pages
- no Force.com Sites

I **do want** to write my own front-end on a separate server that just makes AJAX calls to the Salesforce back-end.

In addition, I want the application to be **accessible for any user**, even if he/she does not have a Salesforce account. So the AJAX calls should not require that the user logs in on Salesforce. I want anonymous users to be able to retrieve public data from my organization and create new entries when it is useful (in the case of a survey for instance).

Even though these requirements generate some security concerns, I can imagine that Salesforce takes care about the requests rate limits on their API endpoints and that it is possible to restrict the access to the API on a host name base (e.g., only requests with origin host `my-trusted-domain.com` should be allowed, send a 403-Forbidden otherwise). I would be surprised if SF does not provide such basic features.

How would you proceed? Is there a minimal Javascript code that works out-of-the-box on any domain without getting into troubles with CORS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All REST API calls to Salesforce must be authenticated.  If you want anonymous API access then you will need to proxy authenticated calls through a server (like on Heroku) that adds the auth token.  Or you can use [Heroku Connect](https://www.heroku.com/connect) to expose your Salesforce data to a Heroku app as a Postrgres database.

If you go the REST route then checkout the [ForceServer](https://github.com/ccoenraets/force-server) and my [CORS Proxy for Salesforce](http://www.jamesward.com/2014/06/23/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-for-salesforce-com).  Both are not setup out-of-the-box for the anonymous access you are looking for but could easily be tweaked to support that use case.

BTW: When allowing anonymous access to your Salesforce data through a proxy make sure you are dealing correctly with security and request limits.

Comment: force.com sites will let you make unauthenticated calls. [that get mapped to the guest user]